# IP address in TCP sockets

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, ip-address

I have a root node(server) connected to many other nodes(clients) through TCP sockets. I want to send some data from server to client, but the data is different for each node and depends on the ip address of that node.

Thus I should have ip address of each node connected to server. How can I have that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have access to the list of file descriptors for the connected TCP sockets, it is easy to retrieve the addresses of the remote hosts. The key is the `getpeername()` system call, which allows you to find out the address of the remote end of a socket. Sample C code:

```c
// This is ugly, but simpler than the alternative
union {
    struct sockaddr sa;
    struct sockaddr_in sa4;
    struct sockaddr_storage sas;
} address;
socklen_t size = sizeof(address);

// Assume the file descriptor is in the var 'fd':
if (getpeername(fd, &address.sa, &size) < 0) {
    // Deal with error here...
}

if (address.sa.family == AF_INET) {
    // IP address now in address.sa4.sin_addr, port in address.sa4.sin_port
} else {
    // Some other kind of socket...
}
```

Comment: If you don't have the FDs, you won't be communicating with those sockets at all…

Comment: This is also basically how you get the values from an `accept()` call (as in cnicutar's answer). It just has the advantage of not needing you to remember it.

Comment: One final remark: getting the host _name_ from an IP address is very expensive (DNS is not optimized for that case) and not necessarily informative either (many hosts don't have reverse records, or the address may be shared because of NAT).

Answer (score 3):

This is a more nuanced question than it first appears.

If the clients are sitting behind a NAT, you may get the same IP from more than one client. This is perfectly natural and expected behavior. If you need to distinguish between multiple clients behind the same NAT, you'll need some other form of unique client id (say, IP address *and* port).

Comment: They are not sitting behind any NAT

Answer (score 2):

When you call [`accept(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) you can choose to retrieve the address of the client.

```
int accept(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address,
    socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

You need to store those addresses and then `send(2)` to each what you need to send.

So the workflow should be something like this:

- Keep a list of connected clients. Initially the list is empty, of course
- When you accept a connection, push its details into that list (the address and the socket returned by `accept(2)`).
- When you need to send something to every client, simply walk the list and send it (using the stored socket)

The one tricky part is that `socklen_t *restrict address_len` is a value-result argument, so you need to be careful with that.